# wix XmlConfig - how to define loc variables?

Tags: wix

I need to use XmlConfig to modify my machine.config file during installation process, something like that:

```
  <util:XmlConfig
    Id="Machine_Config_Xml_Root"
    File="[WindowsFolder]Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\Machine.Config"
    Action="create"
    On="install"
    ElementPath="//configuration/system.data/DbProviderFactories"
    Name="add"
    Node="element"
    Sequence="1">
        </util:XmlConfig>
        <util:XmlConfig
               Id="Machine_Config_Xml_4"
               File="[WindowsFolder]Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\Machine.Config"
               ElementPath="Machine_Config_Xml_Root"
               Name="name"
               Value="My Data Provider"
               Sequence="2">
        </util:XmlConfig>
        <util:XmlConfig
               Id="Machine_Config_Xml_3"
               File="[WindowsFolder]Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\Machine.Config"
               ElementPath="Machine_Config_Xml_Root"
               Name="invariant"
               Value="Sample.MyDataProvider"
               Sequence="2">
        </util:XmlConfig>
        <util:XmlConfig
               Id="Machine_Config_Xml_5"
               File="[WindowsFolder]Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\Machine.Config"
               ElementPath="Machine_Config_Xml_Root"
               Name="description"
               Value="My Data Provider"
               Sequence="2">
        </util:XmlConfig>
        <util:XmlConfig
               Id="Machine_Config_Xml_2"
               File="[WindowsFolder]Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\Machine.Config"
               ElementPath="Machine_Config_Xml_Root"
               Name="type"
               Value="Eli.Sample.MyDataProvider, Sample.MyDataProvider, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5b9d34470b87a97f"
               Sequence="2">
        </util:XmlConfig>

        <util:XmlConfig
           Id="Machine_Config_Xml_Uninstall_1"
           File="[WindowsFolder]Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\Machine.Config"
           Action="delete"
           On="uninstall"
           ElementPath="//configuration/system.data/DbProviderFactories/add[\[]@invariant='Sample.MyDataProvider'[\]]"
           Sequence="1">
        </util:XmlConfig>
```

But it does not compile due to errors like this:

The localization variable !(loc.msierrXmlConfigFailedOpen) is unknown.

How can I define this loc.msierrXmlConfigFailedOpen variable and others? I don't want to switch to en-Us culture (in this case variables are defined) - I need to keep my current culture and define loc variables by myself. How can I do this and where on my wxs file should I put declarations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This phrase you referenced can be found among `UtilExtension` texts. This is the relative path in WiX sources: `/src/ext/UtilExtension/wixlib/en-us.wxl`. As long as you reference the `UtilExtension`, and build the MSI for a different culture (not en-US), you get this error, because there's no translation of this and other phrases you pull along with `UtilExtension`.

You can do the following:

- copy that `en-us.wxl` to your WiX sources and rename it to the culture you target
- replace the values of `<String>` elements in that file with appropriate phrase translations for the culture you target
- feed this file to light.exe (`<localizations>` section)

You might want to utilize the language fallback concept, described in "Specifying Cultures to Build" topic in `WiX.chm`